# When I change locale, whole theme is changed

Tags: android, android-layout

This is so weird.

The best way is to show you a picture:

[image]

I've not set any theme or anything like that, so the default one should be used...

Any idea?

Edit: **It's the same device!!** An android 4.2 emulator.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="es.triiui.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="es.triiui.myapp.Activity_EditDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity__edit_details" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="es.triiui.myapp.AddNewEntry"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_new_entry" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="es.triiui.myapp.ShowDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show_details" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="es.triiui.myapp.Setpassword"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_setpassword" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

(values/styles.xml) is:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
</resources>
```

(values-ca/styles.xml) is:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Both are exactly the same.

Any idea?

Comment: Give us some snippets

Comment: Actually there isn't any snippets that I can give to you... Or just not any relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those XML resources you posted are wrong.

In general, themes go in `themes.xml` (but that shouldn't matter since they're just a style) but more importantly, you don't have a closing `</resources>` tag (copy/paste error?), nor a namespace definition (`xlmns` attribute on `<resources>`).

Both of these should trigger AAPT errors (the missing close tag definitely, the namespace, I'm not sure about - it definitely triggers an Android Lint error!).

Try removing the `values-ca/styles.xml` file. It will default to `values/styles.xml` and you shouldn't see any visual changes.

Comment: well did that, removed the styles file from ca folder; then forced to use a Holo theme `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar">` and it's apparently working correctly. Trying on old devices and such now. I can't understand why it switched themes, because when I did the locale folders, I just copied the "values" folder.

Comment: Oh and by the way, yes, it was a mistake copying. Resources was correctly closed. And the xlmns attribute isn't needed there (or apparently it isn't).

Comment: If I had to guess why that was occurring, I'd say that the locale change forced it to change the theme of an Activity/Window which was already instantiated (you can't do that). I can't get more specific without seeing any of the Activity code (are you handling `configChanges`?) and other parts of the app that might have an effect.

It could also be just a bug, who knows.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, that's exactly it -- the Application's theme changed and you really can't do that once the application has been loaded, so it just reverted to no theme. Mystery solved.

Comment: Ähm... he had a closing tag. You just couldn't see it, since the code wan't formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> I've not set any theme or anything like that, so the default one
>   should be used...

From the documentation of `android:theme`:

> If this attribute is not set, the activity inherits the theme set for
>   the application as a whole — from the `<application>` element's theme
>   attribute. If that attribute is also not set, the default system theme
>   is used

So since you didn't specify a theme it will use the devicedefault theme, therefore the left device uses the holo theme and the right one the pre HC theme.

Comment: and how can this happen, if it's run in the same device, just switching locale?